# Kusto: Failed to cast argument to scalar constant when using countof()

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I defined a UDF function in kusto:

```
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = 'abc', folder='udfs')
get_index_of(input:string, lookup:string)
{
    countof(input, lookup)
}
```

Next, I am going to use it an a sample table and it does not work

```
datatable (Input:string, Lookup:string)
[
    "text:1", ":"
]
    | extend Result = get_index_of(Input, Lookup)
```

I get the error message:

> countof(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant

Do you have any idea what is wrong? Please note, that the function works, because a sample run return result:

```
print get_index_of('text', 'e')
1
```

Answer (score 3):

as of this writing, the 2nd argument to `countof()` is expected to be a *constant* string literal (i.e., one that doesn't change based on row context)

Comment: Found this in July 2022 and it's still true. I was trying to use `countof()` inside of `mv-apply`. :-(